# Get key-values from java object using stream collectors

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I'm trying to get keys and values list from a list of objects using stream and collectorts but I don't know if it is possible.

I have this class:

```
public class MyObject {

    private int key1;

    private String key2;

    private String key3;

    public int getKey1() { return key1; }

    public void setKey1(int key1) { this.key1 = key1; }

    public String getKey2() { return key2; }

    public void setKey2(String key2) { this.key2 = key2; }

    public String getKey3() { return key3; }

    public void setKey3(String key3) { this.key3 = key3; }
}
```

I would like to process a list of this object and get all values and all keys separated by commas.

```
List<MyObject> objectList = myObjectList;
String keys = objectList.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(", ","(", ")"));
String values = Collections.nCopies(objectList.size(), "?").stream().collect(Collectors.joining(", ", " (", ")"));
```

Does anyone know if it is possible? or should I try other option?

Comment: I don't see any values in the `MyObject` class

Comment: Do you mean for List<MyObject> objectList ?

Comment: where are values stored? are they defined within the class?

Comment: values comes from an entry in the method and I want to get them in order to insert in a database

Comment: I've described a method for keys. Please, look over the answer, and ask if something is not clear. If you provide a context where values are in, and what the result you are expecting, I will edit the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For each element of a `Stream<MyObject>`, you can create a `Stream<String>`* of its keys** by the `Stream#flatMap` and `Stream.of`:

```
String keys = objectList
        .stream()
        .flatMap(o -> Stream.of(o.getKey1(), o.getKey2(), o.getKey3()).map(Object::toString))
        .collect(Collectors.joining(",", "(", ")"));
```

*Since some of the fields (keys) are not the `String` type, a `Stream<Object>` can be turned into a `Stream<String>` by the `Stream#map(Object::toString)`.

**The same it is possible with values if you have getters for them.

---

Moving further, I would define a `List` of extractors (`Function<MyObject, String>`) for the class (there can be a static method to return this list):

```
public static List<Function<MyObject, String>> getExtractors() {
    return Arrays.asList(
            o -> String.valueOf(o.getKey1()),
            MyObject::getKey2,
            MyObject::getKey3
    );
}

.flatMap(o -> getExtractors().stream().map(extractor -> extractor.apply(o)))
```

Comment: Or you can convert key 1 to String and get a `Stream<String>` directly: `flatMap(o -> Stream.of(String.valueOf(o.getKey1()), o.getKey2(), o.getKey3()))`